# Symfony app doesn't start properly when using Docker CMD to run a script

Tags: docker, symfony, sh

I am extending a Symfony app Docker image which contains

```
CMD ["unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock"]
```

as the last line of its Dockerfile. In the new image I want to run multiple commands in CMD so I have created a script.

```
#! /bin/sh
echo something
unitd --no-daemon --control unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock
```

And added

```
CMD ["sh", "/path/to/the/script.sh"]
```

to the end of the new Dockerfile. The last line of the script is included because only one CMD can be run and otherwise it wouldn't be executed. But when I run a container made from the new image, Symfony app responds with 502 to all requests. In the console I can see that

> something

is printed, but then the startup freezes after

```
[info] 39#39 OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021, 101010bf
```

When I remove the CMD from the Dockerfile, app starts just fine, meaning the following two lines are printed and app responds normally.

```
[info] 12#12 "symfony" prototype started
[info] 13#13 "symfony" application started
```

Is something wrong with the way I run the script?

Comment: The one big difference to me between the two paths is that, when you have `CMD ["unitd", ...]`, the process manager is the main container process (pid 1), but in your script setup it's a child process of the script.  Does changing the last line to `exec unitd ...` help?

Comment: (Also consider an entrypoint wrapper script here, where the image's `ENTRYPOINT` is a script that does the setup and then `exec "$@"` to switch to the `CMD`; you'd have to repeat the base image's `CMD` here.  Further consider running multiple single-process containers over trying to run multiple processes in a container via a process manager.)

Comment: Changing to last line to `exec unitd ...` didn't help, neither did the ENTRYPOINT you suggested.